# Magento2: Unable to post 2D Array from REST Api

Tags: magento2, api, magento-2.0, rest-api, magento-2.0.7

I am unable to post multi dimensional array from REST API (POST Method).
posting the data in below format.

**RAW DATA**

`{"customerData":{"name":"Mujassam", "no":"7760"}, "services":[{"product":"mobile", "id": "1"}, {"product":"day", "id":"2"}]}`

Here **Services** is **2D Array**

Interface is as below:

`/**
     * return placed order status
     * @api
     * @param string[] $customerData 
     * @param string[] $services
     * @return array
     */
    public function createOrder($customerData, $services);`

May be I am not defining 2D array properly($services)..

It gives me below error

**Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/mabel/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 496**

**Note:** I have no problem passing the 1D array..

Hoping some body to help me..

Comment: Answer has been posted here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326796/how-to-recieve-array-in-request-in-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

You try use hashmap, not array. Magento does not support this type of object.
You can use `KeyValueObject[]` where KeyValueObject is

```
class KeyValueObject
{
  function set/getKey():string
  function set/getValue():string
}
```

see `\Magento\Framework\DataObject\KeyValueObjectInterface` as example

Comment: Thanks for ans @KAndy .. tried method `\Magento\Framework\DataObject\KeyValueObjectInterface` but no luck for me..
it gives me error as below..
**Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface**..
help me if you can

Answer (score -2):

Use  `@param anyType` php doc block in your interface.